# Angular UI Select2 dumping error in console while using in chrome App

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-select2, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to use the following select2 example in **chrome App** using **AngularJS** and **Angular-UI**. It's working fine but unfortunately I'm getting the following error in chrome console every time clicking on the drop boxe. 
"*Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*"

Any suggestion how can i fix this issue?

Thanks

*This code working fine without any problem in browser, but not in chrome App 
**Code:**

Controller

```
 var app = angular.module("app", ['ui']);

function Ctrl($scope) {


    $scope.contacts = [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lucky"},
       {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Lance"},
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Troels"},
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Phe"}
    ];

}
```

View

```
<select class="input-medium" ui-select2 ng-model="form.cont" type="text" value="" >
    <option ng-repeat="contac in all" value="{{contac.id}}">{{contac.name}}</option>               
</select>
```

---

**Solved!**
Thanks to @AlanRodriguesSoares 's tips. I've downloaded another version of select2.js from gitub ( [link] https://raw.github.com/timoxley/select2/bug/onclick/select2.js ) which this issue is fixed in it.

Comment: That select.js is fairly old by this point. Was this ever PR'd back to the project? I'm seeing this in version 0.19.6.

Answer (score 0):

Add the directive ng-csp to your  element:

```
<html ng-app ng-csp>
...
```

With this directive, AngularJS won't use any of the CSP forbidden dynamic JS code, like eval and new Function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have "ng-csp" already in my HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you look on select2.js, there are two "onclick" events set inline, this is a known bug, try removing it.
select.js lines 1524 and 2232.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you talking about *'addSelectedChoice'* & *'createContainer'* method? Actually I removed the *'onClick'* from those two lines. I used to get two errors per click and now I'm getting one error per click ! So you helped me to solve 50% of the issue ;) Do you have any more suggestions?